# Incomparable type when comparing Class objects

Tags: java, factory

I want to create a factory that takes a class type as a parameter to create the corresponding object instance.

But this code doesn't compile:

Java Code:

```
public PropControl Create(Class<? extends PropControl> cls)
{
    if(cls==HouseControl.class) <---- ERROR
    {
       here I create a new instance of HouseControl (that inherits PropControl)
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
incomparable types: Class<CAP#1> and Class<HouseControl>
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends PropControl from capture of ? extends PropControl
```

How do I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: It compiles fine for me with Java 8 (even with Java 7 - http://ideone.com/c5eyxQ). Try to re-clean build your project or recompile your files

Comment: What is your use case? There are many solutions to this problem, so it would be good to understand the larger problem

Comment: Does HouseControl extend PropControl?

Answer (score 0):

HouseControl must extend PropControl, otherwise the condition will never be true and the compiler shows an error.
Example:

```
    Class<? extends InputStream> clazz = null;
    // error: String does not inherit from InputStream, var will never be true.
    boolean var = clazz == String.class;
```

this works:

```
    Class<? extends Object> clazz = null;
    boolean var = clazz == String.class;
```

Comment: it compiles fine now

but I am surprised java does not permit a more OO implementation than a factory or the invoke method,

Java Code:

    public AtomControl Create(Class<? extends AtomControl> cls)
    {
        if(cls==HouseControl.class)
        {
            return HouseControl.Instanciate(null, null, null);
        }
        return null;
    }

I gonna have to check for all classes types with an "if" branch..

Comment: I cant understand there is no better way to format the comments on this site

Comment: @user254885 well in this case you could just do `new HouseControl(null, null, null)`, no comparisons required... Also check out Java naming conventions.

Comment: absolutely not, I need to deal with different types of classes, I just want to avoid a type check, but it seems inpracticable with uninstanciated classes in java

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided will not compile if the class HouseControl did not extends PropControl class. if you want a more generic creational code you can check out this piece of code that uses the Reflection API as a start and adapt for your needs:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class GenericsCreation {

    public <T> T create(Class<? extends T> cls) throws InstantiationException,
                                                   IllegalAccessException,
                                                   NoSuchMethodException,
                                                   IllegalArgumentException,
                                                   InvocationTargetException {
        Constructor<? extends T> constructor = cls.getConstructor(int.class);
        return constructor.newInstance(1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericsCreation test = new GenericsCreation();

        try {
            MyClass instance1  = test.<MyClass>create(MyClass.class);
            MyClass instance1a = test.<MyClass>create(OtherClass.class);
            Object  instance1b = test.<MyClass>create(AnotherClass.class);

            SecondFamilyClass instance2 = test.<SecondFamilyClass>create(SecondFamilyClass.class);
            Object instance2a = test.create(SecondFamilyClass.class);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

class MyClass {
    private int value;
    public MyClass(int param) {
        this.value = param;
    }
}

class OtherClass extends MyClass {
    public OtherClass( int param) {
        super(param);
    }
}

class AnotherClass extends OtherClass {
    public AnotherClass(int param) {
        super(param);
    }
}

class SecondFamilyClass { // Don't extends MyClass
    public SecondFamilyClass(int param) {
        System.out.println("Hey there");
    }
}
```